# Bump/Displacing does not change anything

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, displacement

I'm using Blender 3.3.1 under Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm a newbie with this application and I'm reading the docs and a lot of tutorials.
Given an imported mesh (a cylinder, saved in obj format) I want to displace its surface according to this map:

[image]

Hence I set up the material like this:

[image]

But the actual rendering completely ignores any displacement (and perhaps the roughness map as well):

[image]

What am I missing?
Please feel free to ask any other details you may need, I don't know which other settings are relevant.

For completeness my final goal is to make this cylinder to appear as it was made in [felt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felt#/media/File:Colored_felt_cloth.jpg).

### EDIT

As I wrote in the comment and after the kind answer of Hani Tiby I dont' have the displacement option under Settings:

[image]

Comment: You need 1) to be in Cycles 2) to have enough topology to displace 3) to unwrap your object correctly 4) in the Material panel > Settings > Surface > Displacement, choose Displacement Only

Comment: @moonboots so far I'm stuck at point 1) since each option tells me "No compatible GPUs found for Cycles". But following a tutorial I made it, I saw a real displacement. Doing it by myself from scratch does not work. Surely I'm missing something else.

Comment: Point 2) and 3) I don't know how to be sure they are ok

Comment: Point 4) I don't have such an option for this object

Comment: Could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: 1) just means your GPU is not supported/too weak and you have to render on CPU with Cycles. Select *CPU* from the drop-down menu. It's slow but it will render. 4) You need to switch the render engine to *Cycles* to see these settings.

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you even have a GPU installed in your computer? You might just have a driver issue if you do have a GPU but blender is still not recognizing it.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Ubuntu 22.04 as stated in the question. I'm using the "GPU" embedded into my motherboard: `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation IvyBridge GT2 [HD Graphics 4000]`

Comment: Yeah, that's the built in GPU on you CPU correct? That probably isn't supported for GPU displacement.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Material settings as shown.
You may also need to subdivide the mesh. add Subdivision modifier and set it to simple.

[image]

Comment: Question updated. I don't have such an option. Not sure what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easier solution:

[image]

then I added a particle:

[image]

The result is quite good as first try, even without a decent GPU.

Comment: ok but it would be interesting to find why it didn't work, hard too guess without the file  ;)